# Is any reliable tool available to scan private APIs invoked before submit to app store?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

Try App Scanner, http://www.chimpstudios.com/appscanner/bug  but the reporting result isn't reliable, many of them are fake, so look for more reliable ones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check for private API “usage” yourself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546046/check-for-private-api-usage-yourself)

Comment: whenever i used an undocumented API i got a warning..

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Xcode (4.3 beta) already contains this feature:

> **API Validation**
>
> In the iOS 5 development tools, it is possible to extract APIs used by an application and have them checked for use of private APIs. This option is offered when you validate your application for app submission.

Comment: Thank you.  But I can't find "API Validation" option in my XCode 4.2
, how can I find it?  Thanks.

Comment: Anyone could provide the exact place of this option? A screenshot is better

Comment: It doesn't appear to be listed in the release notes for Xcode 4.3 final (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/).  Perhaps Apple yanked it?

Comment: it's hidden in the `validate archives` function. you will see error messages when private api detected during the process.