# Checking for private APIs from xCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In stack overflow i once read a question on `Private APIs`, and it suggested to install `xCode 4.3.1` stating that there's a feature in it to cross check your application for `private APIs`.

I have lost track of that question, so can someone tell me the steps to check my application for `private APIs` in `xCode 4.3.1` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AppSanner](http://www.chimpstudios.com/appscanner/) and check the code for private api usage. There are several questions with the same topic those are [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546046/check-for-private-api-usage-yourself), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863764/how-to-detect-avoid-the-use-of-private-apis-in-third-party-libraries), and if you are using xcode 4.3 than you can have [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258003/is-any-reliable-tool-avaiabe-to-scan-private-apis-invoked-before-submit-to-app-s)

Try google and you will find plenty of these questions on our community.